# What can silverlight do on client

Tags: silverlight

What is the feature of the silverlight on client side?

My list is

- OpenFileDialog, SaveFileDialog
- Can installed on the client machine
- Possible to use Messagebox
- LocalMessageSender & LocalMessageReceiver
- Work with stream
- Network Monitoring API

After installed on client

- Notification API

Other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly what is the purpose of your question?

There is a stack of things it can do that you haven't listed. If you [visit this page](http://silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/) on the silverlight.net site and just scan down the titles of the tutorial videos it will give you a good list of its capabilities.